# Save file with name from form content

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to save a Microsoft Word 2013 document with a specific filename.

I created a Word form that a client fills out.

I am using the following: DEVELOPER -> Controls -> Plain Text Content Control DEVELOPER -> Controls -> Date Picker Content Control DEVELOPER -> Controls -> Drop-Down List Content Control

I would like a macro to save the document with the name of one of the fields in the form.

Example:
below are fillable content fields.

```
client reference: A1B2-345
date: August 17, 2015
type: metadata
```

I would like to save the file as:

```
A1B2-345_17082015_metadata.DOCX
```

Comment: Automatically save it when? What triggers the save?

Comment: Bond,
actually, because of your comment I understand that I do not want to automatically save the document, rather save it upon running the macro.

Comment: Are you using a _Content Textbox_, a _legacy text form field_, or an _ActiveX text box_?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I am using the following:
DEVELOPER -> Controls -> Plain Text Content Control
DEVELOPER -> Controls -> Date Picker Content Control
DEVELOPER -> Controls -> Drop-Down List Content Control

Answer (score 0):

Start by giving each of your controls a `Title`. You can do this by clicking on your control in your document and then click `Properties` on the `Developer` ribbon. The first field on the `Properties` window is `Title`. Give each one of the controls you need to access a unique title. In the example below, I'm using `MyText`, `MyDate`, and `MyDrop` for the text, date, and drop-down controls, respectively.

Then you can access each control in VBA by using the `SelectContentControlsByTitle()` function. As long as you're using a unique title, this function will return a collection containing only a single control so we can just retrieve the first item from the collection (index `(1)`). Here's how this would look:

```
Dim strText As String, strDate As String, strDrop As String

strText = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("MyText")(1).Range.Text
strDate = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("MyDate")(1).Range.Text
strDrop = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("MyDrop")(1).Range.Text
```

The `Range.Text` ending is what grabs the current text/value from the control.

Now that you have your three pieces of information, you can concatenate them into one string using the concatenation operator (`&`):

```
Dim strFilename As String
strFilename = strText & "_" & Format(strDate, "ddmmyyyy") & "_" & strDrop & ".docx"
```

And, finally, save it:

```
ThisDocument.SaveAs strFilename
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the code provided above will not work properly if you are generating the form based off a template (.dotm).  The following lines that include the `ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle` need to be changed to 
`ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle` otherwise the code will pull the place holder text from the content control.